# How can I protect a extarcted embedded resource?

Tags: c#

So I am working on a project where I need to build a login application that grants access to a embedded executable resource. I've been searching and didn't found a way to do that. From what a gatter, I cannot just execute without extracting it. So there must be a way for me to put a lock on the executable, like a password, this way, only my program will be able to access it. I do not have the source code for the executable. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Please define embedded executable resource.

Comment: Note that a good many anti virus apps are going to shriek in horror at your app.

Comment: You want to change the behavior of someone else's executable, without having the source code?  You could learn assembly, disassemble it, and find a place to patch in your password check or command line check.  Otherwise, nope.  Talk to the owner of the application about making you a custom build.

Comment: Is this other application a .NET application or is it a native app?

Comment: It's a normal .exe file. The whole point of the application is to protect it.

Comment: I gess that what I am looking for is a windows resource that allows me to put some sort of password in any file, like a winrar password. So that I can block this executable from anyone accessing it, except from my application.

Comment: Yes, but is the exe a .net exe or is it a non-.net exe? It matters because I think i have a solution for .net but I don't have a solution if it is not a .net exe. Tell me if you do `Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Path\to\other\program.exe");` (using the real filepath of course) does it work without a error or does it throw an exception. That will tell us if it is .net or not.

Comment: Scott, that line of code of yours doesn't throw any Exception. But it doesn't open the file either (i dont know if it's supose to do that). I Loaded from my Desktop, and not from the Resources as well

Comment: extract it, execute it, wait for it to exit, delete it.  Use `Process.WaitForExit()`.  Then `File.Delete()`.

Comment: Hum, so this will execute the file and when he get closed he is also deleted right? What if the user tries to copy and paste the file while he is open?

Comment: @FiREBiRD creating a bullet proof security access solution to user installed files is non trivial and would be impossible from user mode. However, you can encrypt it as a resource i guess, though it has many attack vectors. Thats to say, there is no safe way to stop people just copying the file once its been decrypted. even if its in memory, there are many approaches people can use to beat this sort of system

Comment: Ok man Thanks. That's all I needed to know, that there is no way to fully protect :)

Comment: @FiREBiRD however you can make it harder, especially if your users arent super nerds

Answer (score 1):

Because the other app is a .net application (You said it did not throw an execption when you did a `Assembly.LoadFile` in the comments) you can just load the exe as a byte array in to your AppDomain then run the assembly from memory.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data = SomeFunctionThatRetrunsTheBytesOfTheExeResource()

    var assembly = Assembly.Load(data);
    assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

This will start the app you did as a embedded resource. Be aware that the `Invoke(null, null)` function will block till the other program returns from it's main method.

This will allow you to run the exe without it ever existing as it's own file on the drive.

Note: This will make the new app share the same memory space as your app, so it can do things like access your static variables and classes. You might be able to create a new AppDomain and load it there instead (but when I tried to do it to write this up I could not make it work in a 2nd AppDomain).

2nd Note: Without running your app through a code obfusactor that can obfuscate resources it will be trivially easy to extract the exe from your program using any free .net decompiler.